# VMWare NAT configuration

Tags: networking, vmware, dns

I am trying to run the latest Ubuntu Desktop as a guest inside VMWare Workstation. I need to use NAT for internet access and access to the other Virtual Machines. This works flawlessly on all of my Windows guest machines. On the Windows host I have the following ipconfig information for my VMNet8 adapter.

```
Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.28.1(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

For my Ubuntu machine I have put the following in /etc/network/interfaces

```
auth eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.28.12
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.28.2
dns-nameservers 192.168.28.2
```

With this information I can only ping other virtual machines and the internet by IP address. Using the machine name or www.google.com will not work.

If I add 8.8.8.8 as a dns-nameserver as well I can of course hit the internet by using google.com, but I still have to use an IP for my internal network. I need some help on this, I have tried multiple things. I have to believe it's not an issue with my Hosts configuration since it works on my Windows machines just fine.

NOTE: If I change Ubuntu to get IP via DHCP I can ping other virtual machines on my network, but still not internet name resolution. I also can not SSH into the Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

from your configuration, you are using NAT however assigning the IP address manually from the range in your router. Usually the VMWare or VBox NAT has different IP Range Pool than the actual router's (192.168.x.x). As you are using the 192.168.28.12, you need to switch the network from NAT to Bridged mode. Your gateway is 192.168.28.2, how do you know? as per the output result for your vmware adapter the gateway is 28.1

If you really want to use the NAT then you need to add the routing entry. Can you paste the output of your routing table?
In addition, find out the NAT Pool IP range in your hypervisor.

Comment: First let me say I have had issues with NAT in every other Linux distribution I have tried. I have posted in the CentOS, Fedora, & Debian forums and you are the first to even respond. So thank you.

Comment: I am in a situation where I -have- to use NAT as I cannot put the machine on the same LAN as the Host with it's own IP, as I cannot get a lease for another IP. The gateway according to the Virtual Network Editor through VMWare is 192.168.28.2. Here is my route -n. `code Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.28.2    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.28.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0 `

Comment: Also if I were to go with DHCP the IP range would be 192.168.28.128 -> .254. Pulling from DHCP will allow me to ping internal machines but still no Internet.